# Unable to get iOS 9.3 update OTA

Tags: iphone, software-update

iOS 9.3 was released yesterday, so I wanted it on my iPhone 5s. However when I try to open Settings → General → Software Update, it pops up with a message:

> Unable to Check for Update, an error occurred while checking for a software update.

I tried several things found on the internet like resetting the network settings, changing the DNS, switching to cellular network, but I am still getting the same error.

How can I download iOS 9.3 OTA?

Comment: Just after a new iOS release, the servers get swamped for a while. Answer is normally just to wait, or maybe try it around 7 to 9am GMT, that's when the net as a whole is at its quietest. US going to bed, EU just getting up.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first 24 hours are the hardest. Since the servers are busy pushing out the update for millions of devices.

If it doesn't work after that, you might have to go for the update via iTunes.